# web scrape with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to grab a table of data using read_html from the r package rvest.

I've tried the below code:

```
library(rvest)
  raw <- read_html("https://demanda.ree.es/movil/peninsula/demanda/tablas/2016-01-02/2")
```

I don't believe the above pulled the data from the table, since I see 'raw' is a list of 2:

```
'node:<externalptr>' and  'doc:<externalptr>'
```

I've tried grabbing the xpath too:

```
html_nodes(raw,xpath = '//*[(@id = "tabla_generacion")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ng-scope", " " ))]')
```

Any advice on what to try next?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This website is using angular to make a call to get the data. You can just use that call to get the raw JSON. The response is not pure JSON, so you can't just run `fromJSON(url)`, you have to download the data and get rid of the non-JSON stuff before you parse it.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
url <- "https://demanda.ree.es/WSvisionaMovilesPeninsulaRest/resources/demandaGeneracionPeninsula?callback=angular.callbacks._2&curva=DEMANDA&fecha=2016-01-02"
a <- GET(url)
a <- content(a, as="text")
# get rid of the non-JSON stuff...
a <- gsub("^angular.callbacks._2\\(", "", a)
a <- gsub("\\);$", "", a)
df <- fromJSON(a, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
```

I found this by pushing F12 in Chrome and looking at the "Sources" tab. The data to fill the table had to come from somewhere... so it's just a matter of figuring out where. I was unable to use rvest to scrape the table. I'm not sure if that call to get the data was executed in R as it was in chrome... so there may have been no data for rvest to scrape.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any chance you could explain where you found that call? Can it be found by using "inspect" in Chrome?

Comment: very cool, thanks for the explanation. This will come in handy for me.

Comment: @cory looks like an interesting solution...do you think you could help with this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208566/webscrape-tables-on-websites-that-use-angularjs-using-r) ?