# Scraping PHP dashboard with R (rvest)

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, dashboard, rvest

I am trying to scrape Bangladesh COVID-19 data (number of tests, number of positive tests, positive rate) from the official website: http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php

The website contains 3 drop-down menus to arrive at the data: Select Division; Select District; Select time frame for the data.

I have tried the following so far:

```
url <- "http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php"
webpage <- read_html(url)
```

`webpage` has the following:

```
List of 2
 $ node:<externalptr> 
 $ doc :<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

Since this did not help, I also tried the following based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335498/web-scrape-with-rvest):

```
a <- GET(url)
a <- content(a, as="text")
a <- gsub("^angular.callbacks._2\\(", "", a)
a <- gsub("\\);$", "", a)
df <- fromJSON(a, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
```

The above returns the following error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <!-- This is a 
                     (right here) ------^
```

So I am really lost in terms of how I can even read the data - but upon looking at the source of the webpage, I know that the data is right there: [Safari Website inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAQNV.png)

Any suggestions on how I can read this data?

Additionally, if someone could help with how I can go about selecting the different drop-down menu items, that would be really appreciated. The final goal is to collect data for each district in each division for the last 12 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The page makes additional requests to pick up that info. Those additional requests rely on combinations of ids; an id pulled from the `option` element `value` attribute, of each option within `Division` dropdown, in tandem with an id pulled from the `option` element `value` attribute of each option within the `District` dropdown.

You can make an initial request to get all the `Division` dropdown ids:

```
divisions <- options_df("#division option:nth-child(n+2)", "division")
```

`nth-child(n+2)` is used to exclude the initial 'select' option.

This returns a dataframe with the initial `divisionIDs` and friendly division names.

[image]

Those ids can then be used to retrieve the associated `districtIDs` (the options which become available in the second dropdown after making your selection in the first):

```
districts <- pmap_dfr(
  list(divisions$divisionID),
  ~ {
    df_districts <- districts_from_updated_session(.x, "district") %>%
      mutate(
        divisionID = .x
      )
    return(df_districts)
  }
)
```

This returns a dataframe mapping the `divisionID` to all the associated `districtIDs`, as well as the friendly district names:

[image]

By including the `divisionID` in both dataframes I can inner-join them:

```
div_district <- dplyr::inner_join(divisions, districts, by = "divisionID", copy = FALSE)
```

[image]

Up until now, I have been using a session object for the efficiency of tcp re-use. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the documentation covering how to update an already open session allowing for sending a new `POST` request with dynamic body argument.  Instead, I leveraged `furrr::future_map` to try and gain some efficiencies through parallel processing:

```
df <- div_district %>%
  mutate(json = furrr::future_map(divisionID, .f = get_covid_data, districtID))
```

To get the final covid numbers, via `get_covid_data()`, I leverage some perhaps odd behaviour of the server, in that I could make a `GET`, passing `divisionID` and `districtID` within the body, then regex out part of the jquery datatables scripting, string clean that into a json valid string, then read that into a json object stored in the `json` column of the final dataframe.

[image]

Inside of the `json` column

[image]

---

**R:**

```r
library(httr)
#> Warning: package 'httr' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> Warning: package 'xml2' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(jsonlite)
#> Warning: package 'jsonlite' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     flatten
library(furrr)
#> Warning: package 'furrr' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Loading required package: future
#> Warning: package 'future' was built under R version 4.0.3

## to clean out everything before a run
# rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
# invisible(lapply(paste0('package:', names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)), detach, character.only=TRUE, unload=TRUE)) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235076 @mmfrgmpds

#returns value:text for options e.g. divisions/districts (dropdown)
options_df <- function(css_selector, level) {
  nodes <- session %>% html_nodes(css_selector)
  options <- nodes %>% map_df(~ c(html_attr(., "value"), html_text(.)) %>%
    set_names(paste0(level, "ID"), level))
  return(options)
}

#returns districts associated with division
districts_from_updated_session <- function(division_id, level) {
  session <- jump_to(session, paste0("http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/ajaxDataDistrictDHIS2Dashboard.php?division_id=", division_id))
  return(options_df("#district option:nth-child(n+2)", level))
}

# returns json object housing latest 12 month covid numbers by divisionID + districtID pairing
get_covid_data <- function(divisionID, districtID) {
  headers <- c(
    "user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0",
    "if-modified-since" = "Wed, 08 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT" # to mitigate for caching
  )

  data <- list("division" = divisionID, "district" = districtID, "period" = "LAST_12_MONTH", "Submit" = "Search")

  r <- httr::GET(url = "http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php", httr::add_headers(.headers = headers), body = data)

  data <- stringr::str_match(content(r, "text"), "DataTable\\((\\[[\\s\\S]+\\])\\)")[1, 2] %>% #clean up extracted string so can be parsed as valid json
    gsub("role", '"role"', .) %>%
    gsub("'", '"', .) %>%
    gsub(",\\s+\\]", "]", .) %>%
    str_squish() %>%
    jsonlite::parse_json()
  return(data)
}


url <- "http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php"
headers <- c("User-Agent" = "Mozilla/4.0", "Referer" = "http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php")

session <- html_session(url, httr::add_headers(.headers = headers)) #for tcp re-use

divisions <- options_df("#division option:nth-child(n+2)", "division") #nth-child(n+2) to exclude initial 'select' option

districts <- pmap_dfr(
  list(divisions$divisionID),
  ~ {
    df <- districts_from_updated_session(.x, "district") %>%
      mutate(
        divisionID = .x
      )
    return(df)
  }
)

div_district <- dplyr::inner_join(divisions, districts, by = "divisionID", copy = FALSE)

no_cores <- future::availableCores() - 1

future::plan(future::multisession, workers = no_cores)

df <- div_district %>%
  mutate(json = future_map(divisionID, .f = get_covid_data, districtID))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

**Py**

```
import requests, re, ast
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def options_dict(soup, css_selector):
    options = {i.text:i['value'] for i in soup.select(css_selector) if i['value']}
    return options

def covid_numbers(text):
    covid_data = p.findall(text)[0]
    covid_data = re.sub(r'\n\s+', '', covid_data.replace("role","'role'"))
    covid_data = ast.literal_eval(covid_data) 
    return covid_data

url = 'http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php'
regions = {}
result = {}
p = re.compile(r'DataTable\((\[[\s\S]+\])\)')

with requests.Session() as s: 
    s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Referer': 'http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php'}
    soup = bs(s.get(url).content, 'lxml')
    divisions = options_dict(soup, '#division option')

    for k,v in divisions.items():
        r = s.get(f'http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/ajaxDataDistrictDHIS2Dashboard.php?division_id={v}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        districts = options_dict(soup, '#district option')
        regions[k] = districts
   
    s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0','if-modified-since': 'Wed, 08 Jul 2020 22:27:07 GMT'}
    
    for k,v in divisions.items():
        result[k] = {}
        for k2,v2 in regions.items():    
            data = {'division': k2, 'district': v2, 'period': 'LAST_12_MONTH', 'Submit': 'Search'}
            r = s.get('http://103.247.238.92/webportal/pages/covid19.php',  data=data)
            result[k][k2] = covid_numbers(r.text)
```